# Policies with extra parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization

I know, how to use Laravel policies and everything works, but I am stuck with `create(...)` method.

My app is a training diary for ski racers. Each *racer* can manage (view, add, edit..) his own diary. Each *trainer* can manage his own diary, diary of all racers but not other trainers. I use native Laravel Policies and it works great during *`update(...)` and `delete(...)` method, but not `create(...)`.

TrainingRecordPolicy.php:

```
public function update(User $user, TrainingRecord $record)
{
    if ($user->id == $record->user->id) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($user->isTrainer() && $record->user->isRacer()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm using it in controllers like `$this->authorize('update', $record)`. But if I want to check, if user can create new record into others user diary, I have no idea how to deal with it.

This doesn't work `$this->authorize('create', TrainingRecord::class, $diaryOwner)` and if I use `$this->authorize('createDiaryRecord', $diaryOwner)` it calls method inside `UserPolicy`.

How do I send `$diaryOwner` as extra parameter to `create()` method within the policy?

> **Note**: `$diaryOwner` is retrieved from the route parameter `user` in route with signature `/diary/{user}`

Comment: How do you get `$diaryOwner`?

Comment: From route parameter: `/diary/{user}/new-record`. There is no detail (view) of TrainingRecord. There is only table for whole season, where all records are listed in something like calendar agenda.

Comment: So in the example `$this->authorize('create', ..., $diaryOwner)` `$diaryOwner` is instance of User or just `id`? What is the relationship between User model and Diary model? Add it to the OP.

Comment: There is no model `Diary`. There are 2 models `TrainingRecord` and `User`. User can have more records. In route `/diary/{user}` you can see all `TrainingRecords` of user in something like calendar agenda. You can think about it as calendar. You have calendar, your trainer has calendar. He can write into your own one. But you cannot write into his

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the `$diaryOwner` within the policy using `request()` helper.

```
public function create(User $user) 
{
    $diaryOwner = request()->user; // because route is defined as /diary/{user}
}
```

There may be a problem because:

> When using dynamic properties, Laravel will first look for the parameter's value in the request payload. If it is not present, Laravel will search for the field in the route parameters.

So instead of using `request()->user` use `request()->route()->parameter('user')`.

Also if you are using `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` you will get `User` instance.